# ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2) while uploading multiple files

Tags: python, exception, strava

I was trying to upload multiple files by Strava API.

While running the `uploadFitActivity()` method, it caused `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)`

I believe this exception is raised by my `uploadFitActivity()` method, maybe related to `f = {'file' : fitfile}`in the `for` loop. But I can not figure out the actual problem and what the exception is pointing to.

Below is my `uploadFitActivity()` method:

```
def uploadFitActivity(dirpath, access_token):
    uploads_url = "https://www.strava.com/api/v3/uploads"
    payload = {
        'client_id': client_ID,
        'data_type': 'fit' }
    header = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token}

    os.chdir(dirpath)
    for filename in glob.glob("*.fit"):
        with open(filename, 'rb') as fitfile:
            f = {'file' : fitfile}
            res = requests.post( uploads_url,
                                 data = payload,
                                 headers = header,
                                 files = f )
```

Comment: Can you post the full traceback?

Comment: You are trying to unpack something into two variables somewhere, but that data structure has more elements than that.

Comment: Example of trying to unpack a data structure with 3 elements into two variables:
```>>> a,b = (1,2,3)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)```